# (#322) Subject does not have permission to tag this photo - Facebook PHP SDK v4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to **tag** one people in my facebook fanpage photo using **Facebook PHP SDK v4**

```
        $args = array();
        $args['access_token'] = $page_info['access_token'];
        $args['message'] = $data['message'];
        $args['url'] = $data['src_big']['source'];

        $post = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', "/$page_id/photos", $args))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
        var_dump($post);
```

> Photo posted successfully.

But when I try to add a tag

```
        $tag = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', "/{$post['id']}/tags/{$data['from']['id']}"))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

it's returning

> (#322) Subject does not have permission to tag this photo

not even tag array working.

```
        $args['tags'] = array( array( 'tag_uid' => $data['from']['id'], 'x' => 0, 'y' => 0 ) );
```

This returning

> param tags must be an array.

I have no idea how to do it. Please anybody help me doing this.

Comment: Where’s the access token in your second API call? Since you did not provide your page access token as with the first one, this request will be made using the user access token (if any is set, or else just the app access token.)

Comment: $tag = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', "/{$post['id']}/tags/{$data['from']['id']}", array('access_token' => $accessToken)))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray(); not working with page token, even user token

Answer (score 0):

You would need the publish_action permission to tag a photo.

Comment: I have following permissions sir $permissions = array(
 'email',
 'user_location',
 'user_birthday',
 'publish_actions',
 'manage_pages',
 'publish_pages',
 'user_about_me',
 'user_hometown',
 'user_groups',
 'user_likes',
 'user_photos',
 'user_website'
); but still not working.